# Area of triangle with 3 sides

Tags: algorithm, assembly, geometry, arm, trigonometry

I was trying to find the area of the triangle to code in assembly on raspberry pi 4 but I am only allowed to have the user input 2 inputs which is the length and width of the rectangle. Is it even possible to find the the values of the sides of the triangle (s1, s2, s3) with just 2 inputs? like I know s2 will be the length of the rectangle but how about the other 2 sides? I don't think i can also compare s1+s3>s3 as well.
[image: triangle and a rectangle]

Comment: Are you allowed to assume it's a right-angle triangle?  If which two lengths you have relative to the right-angle, then it's just pythagoras to get the 3rd side.  (This seems like more of an algorithm question than an assembly implementation question, since you're not asking about any code, and the answer depends on geometry and trigonometry, not assembly.  e.g. Euclid could maybe have answered.)

Comment: mm i doubt so because i am supposed to find the area of the figure as shown through assembly code, but I am going to check again to see if there is any pre-defined values for the other sides. thanks!

Comment: c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) is no harder than any other formula in asm, the ARM in an RPi has an FPU with hardware sqrt and divide, so I don't see why asm being the target language would have any effect on what assumptions you should make.

Comment: What do you call length ? What do you call width ?? [My bet is that the solution is trivial.]

Comment: review your elementary math, you need three things, either the lengths of the three sides or you need two lengths and the angle between them.  Then simply implement the math from grade school.

Comment: unless what you mean is the width as in the length of the line that is shared between the rectangle and triangle and then the height of the peak from that line at a 90 degree angle from that width.  Then of course you can find the area, quite trivial actually.

Comment: likewise, of course, you can find the lengths of the other two sides of the triangle

Comment: solve the math problem first, then simply program it in whatever programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your drawing with a triangle above the rectangle: No.

Just the dimensions of the rectangle is not enough, because the "triangle point" could be moved around to change the sides.

Comment: okay thank you so much! I shall go double check again. Thanks for the confirmation!